# Nuances between "je ne dirais pas non à X" and "je n'aurais rien contre X"

Tags: sens, usage

I just said in conversation:

> Sincèrement, **je n’aurais** d’ailleurs **pas dit non à** un peu de repos bien merité.
>
> {vs}: Sincèrement, **je n’aurais** d’ailleurs **rien eu contre** un peu de repos bien merité.

Q1. I wonder if these two expressions are more or less interchangeable?

Q2. Are they both considered *litotes*, making them sound as if I'd *really* have liked to take a break?

Q3. Is it acceptable to use the constructions "à + *infinitif*" and "contre + *infinitif*" with these expressions?

> Sincèrement, je n’aurais d’ailleurs pas dit non **à prendre** un peu de repos bien merité.
>
> Sincèrement, je n’aurais d’ailleurs rien eu **contre prendre** un peu de repos bien merité.

Answer (score 4):

> Q1. I wonder if these two expressions are more or less
>   interchangeable?

Yes, they are. They mean the same thing : If the statement happened, you wouldn't mind. Even more, you regret it did not happened.

> Q2. Are they both considered litotes, making them sound as if I'd
>   really have liked to take a break?

In my own opinion, yes, they are. Because of their negative construction. (But I'm not a french professor. Even if I'm french, I'm not expert in figure of speech)

> Q3. Is it acceptable to use the constructions "à + infinitif" and
>   "contre + infinitif"? Or should they take the form of "au fait de +
>   infinitif" and "contre le fait de + infinitif"?

Yes, it's acceptable.

**Little french tip :** after "de" or "à", there will always be an "infinitif" (if it's a verb).

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. I wonder if these two expressions are more or less interchangeable?

These two expressions are totally interchangeable and I actually fail to see any difference between them aside from their construction.

> Q2. Are they both considered litotes, making them sound as if I'd really have liked to take a break?

They both are *litotes* to me. Both basically implicitly mean that the rest would have been more than welcomed. The "**bien merité**" here seems a bit redundant to me, though.

> Q3. Is it acceptable to use the constructions "à + infinitif" and "contre + infinitif" with these expressions?

It is acceptable to me. The first one I'm pretty sure is correct, but for the second one, I find it a little odd to be adding "**prendre**" to it.

Comment: Hi. About Q3, I share your uneasiness about using *infinitif* with these expressions. I feel more comfortable placing a ***noun*** immediately after the prepositions. Then again, it seems redundant, if not odd, to say "***le fait de prendre***".

Comment: Hello. Well, it really doesn't seem incorrect grammatically speaking, but that just doesn't feel right to me. "_**Je n'aurai rien eu contre prendre du repos bien mérité**_" sounds way better to me.

Comment: @Alone-zee saying no to a fact is weird as well. Maybe "je n'aurai pas dit non à l'idée de prendre un peu de repos"

Answer (score 0):

**A**

Tout d'abord, il faut se rendre compte que la construction de ces phrases est d'une lourdeur assez irritante ; « sincèrement » est un jugement concernant l'énonciation ; en utilisant une forme explicite on a les phrases suivantes ;
- Il faut le croire, je n'aurais d'ailleurs pas dit non […]

- Il faut croire que je n'aurais d'ailleurs rien eu contre […]

Le complément circonstanciel « d'ailleurs » constitue un autre jugement à propos d'une énonciation ; il est ici placé après l'auxiliaire, mais ce n'est qu'une option parmi d'autres pour l'introduire dans une phrase ;

« d'ailleurs, je n'aurais pas dit non […] » est totalement équivalent à « Je n'aurais d'ailleurs pas dit non […] »

> Selon le TLFi, au moyen de « d'ailleurs » on  indique un changement de plan logique et  on ajoute un élément nouveau sans rapport nécessaire avec ce que l'on vient de dire [et qui renforce ce qui a été dit]

Dans les phrases considérées cet élément nouveau est le fait que l'on n'aurais pas dit non […]

Une forme explicite donne l'équivalent suivant :

- Je le dit en renforcement à ce qui a été dit, je n'aurais pas dit non […]

Le résultat de ces équivalences est la phrase suivante ;

- Il faut le croire, je dit en renforcement à ce qui a été dit que je n'aurais pas dit non […]

Il y a donc un jugement qui porte sur un autre : on doit légitimement reconnaitre le premier comme portant sur le second, tout au moins dans la construction originale.

Si l'on pense que les deux jugements peuvent se combiner on se trompe ; la forme suivante n'est pas équivalente et d'ailleurs elle ne communique pas un état de chose défini ; selon une pratique établie le premier jugement porterait sur ce qui suit la première virgule, à moins que l'on interprète cette virgule comme une virgule de coordination, un simple « et », mais alors on a la seconde phrase, qui n'est pas équivalente.

1. **a** Il faut le croire, je le dit en renforcement à ce qui a été dit,  je n'aurais pas dit non […]
   **b** Sincèrement, d'ailleurs, je n'aurais pas dit non […] (On ne trouve pas cette combinaison)
2. **a** Il faut le croire et je le dit en renforcement à ce qui a été dit,  je n'aurais rien eu contre […]
   **b**  Sincèrement et d'ailleurs, je n'aurais rien eu contre […] (Il y a encore moins de chance de trouver cette combinaison-ci)

   Une construction appropriée se trouve dans la phrase suivante, dans laquelle est  utilisée une incise;

   - D'ailleurs, -- je le dis sincèrement --, je n'aurais pas dit non  […]

**B**

Les réponses aux trois questions sont faite sur la base des phrases « récupérées ».

- D'ailleurs, je n'aurais pas dit non à un peu de repos bien mérité, sincèrement.
- D'ailleurs, je n'aurais rien eu contre un peu de repos bien mérité, sincèrement.

**Q1** Le sens n'est pas strictement équivalent ; « ne pas dire non » et « ne rien avoir contre » n'ont pas la même signification ; on peut avoir beaucoup à dire contre quelque chose et tout en même temps dire oui à cette chose.

- Je n'aurais pas dit non bien que j'avais beaucoup à redire à cette idée de transporter les voyageurs dans des wagons à marchandise.

Néanmoins, dans un contexte simple, les deux seront comprises à peu près comme un quasi oui.

**Q2** D'après leur construction (double négation) ces expressions sont sans aucun doute des litotes ; la double négation est un [moyen souvent utilisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litote) pour formuler une litote.

**Q3** Il n'y a aucun principe qui se dégage clairement contre cet usage (c'est à dire, que je puisse percevoir) mais il ne semble pas imprimer avec assez de force dans l'esprit la signification qu'on en attend. Il semble cependant que les substantifs sont assez naturels dans ce contexte grammatical. Dans les exemples suivants je préfère nettement les phrases avec le substantif.

- Ils ont dit non à partir de bonne heure./Ils ont dit non à un départ de bonne heure.
- Elle a dit non à rechercher ces connections théoriques./Elle à dit non à la recherche de ces connections théoriques.
- La famille a dit non à manger de tels ingrédients./La famille a dit non à la consommation de tels ingrédients.

Possibilités d'utilisation d'un substantif

- D'ailleurs, je n'aurais pas dit non **à la prise d'un peu de repos** bien mérité, sincèrement.
- D'ailleurs, je n'aurais rien eu contre **la prise d'un peu de repos** bien mérité, sincèrement.

D'autres combinaisons peuvent remplacer « à la prise de repos », qui est assez « neutre » et [pas tout à fait naturel](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prise+de+repos&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprise%20de%20repos%3B%2Cc0) au locuteur français : « **au/le réconfort d'un peu de repos** », « **au/le bienfait réparateur d'un peu de repos** »,